# JFace TreeView showing 2 vertical scrollbars

Tags: eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am upgrading an old RCP app to use eclipse 2023-06. There are 2 views which are showing doubled vertical scrollbars. Both use `TreeViewer`.

[image]

The part is initialised as follows:

```
viewer = new TreeViewer(body, SWT.NORMAL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
viewer.setContentProvider(new ProtocolViewContentProvider());
viewer.setLabelProvider(lp);
comparator = new ProtocolViewerComparator();
viewer.setComparator(comparator);

viewer.getTree().setLinesVisible(true);
viewer.getTree().setHeaderVisible(true);
viewer.getTree().setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
```

I have tried creating the `TreeViewer` using just the `body` parameter but there is no change.

If I remove the header the 2 scrollbars are the same height.

`SWT Spy` does not give me any further insights...

```
Tree {} [layout=null]@140368
    Style: SINGLE | HORIZONTAL | VERTICAL | FULL_SELECTION | LEFT_TO_RIGHT | DOUBLE_BUFFERED 
    Layout Data: GridData {horizontalAlignment=SWT.FILL grabExcessHorizontalSpace=true verticalAlignment=SWT.FILL grabExcessVerticalSpace=true}
    Bounds: Rectangle {0, 27, 1120, 211}


Children:

Peers:
    Label {TestCases - [Aktuell] }@140364 Layout Data: GridData {horizontalAlignment=SWT.BEGINNING verticalAlignment=GridData.CENTER} Bounds: Rectangle {0, 0, 130, 17}
    *Tree {} [layout=null]@140368 Layout Data: GridData {horizontalAlignment=SWT.FILL grabExcessHorizontalSpace=true verticalAlignment=SWT.FILL grabExcessVerticalSpace=true} Bounds: Rectangle {0, 27, 1120, 211}

Parent Tree:
    Shell {gitr3a-workspace-developer - TestCases/5BE86209-DD55-4EA8-9BB7-ECA48CE1D883.cfg - Title} [layout=org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.TrimmedPartLayout@2cf78ff]@1122090
         Style: RESIZE | TITLE | CLOSE | MIN | MAX | LEFT_TO_RIGHT 
         Bounds: Rectangle {3621, -1337, 1741, 1568}
         Layout: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.TrimmedPartLayout@2cf78ff
         LayoutData: null
        Composite {} [layout=FillLayout {type=SWT.HORIZONTAL}]@1055872
             Style: LEFT_TO_RIGHT 
             Bounds: Rectangle {0, 28, 1719, 1428}
             Layout: FillLayout {type=SWT.HORIZONTAL}
             LayoutData: null
            Composite {} [layout=org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashLayout@5ec40569]@663364
                 Style: LEFT_TO_RIGHT 
                 Bounds: Rectangle {0, 0, 1719, 1428}
                 Layout: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashLayout@5ec40569
                 LayoutData: null
                Composite {} [layout=StackLayout {topControl=Composite {} [layout=FillLayout {type=SWT.HORIZONTAL}]}]@791434
                     Style: LEFT_TO_RIGHT 
                     Bounds: Rectangle {0, 0, 1719, 1428}
                     Layout: StackLayout {topControl=Composite {} [layout=FillLayout {type=SWT.HORIZONTAL}]}
                     LayoutData: null
                    Composite {} [layout=FillLayout {type=SWT.HORIZONTAL}]@1053782
                         Style: LEFT_TO_RIGHT 
                         Bounds: Rectangle {0, 0, 1719, 1428}
                         Layout: FillLayout {type=SWT.HORIZONTAL}
                         LayoutData: null
                        Composite {} [layout=org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashLayout@419a1073]@986112
                             Style: LEFT_TO_RIGHT 
                             Bounds: Rectangle {0, 0, 1719, 1428}
                             Layout: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashLayout@419a1073
                             LayoutData: null
                            CTabFolder {} [layout=org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolderLayout@7aa5596f]@663188
                                 Style: MULTI | TOP | BORDER | NO_REDRAW_RESIZE | LEFT_TO_RIGHT | DOUBLE_BUFFERED 
                                 Bounds: Rectangle {579, 1153, 1140, 275}
                                 Layout: org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolderLayout@7aa5596f
                                 LayoutData: null
                                Composite {} [layout=FillLayout {type=SWT.HORIZONTAL}]@664042
                                     Style: LEFT_TO_RIGHT 
                                     Bounds: Rectangle {10, 26, 1120, 238}
                                     Layout: FillLayout {type=SWT.HORIZONTAL}
                                     LayoutData: null
                                    ContributedPartRenderer$1 {} [layout=FillLayout {type=SWT.VERTICAL}]@598508
                                         Style: LEFT_TO_RIGHT 
                                         Bounds: Rectangle {0, 0, 1120, 238}
                                         Layout: FillLayout {type=SWT.VERTICAL}
                                         LayoutData: null
                                        Composite {} [layout=FillLayout {type=SWT.HORIZONTAL}]@1188326
                                             Style: LEFT_TO_RIGHT 
                                             Bounds: Rectangle {0, 0, 1120, 238}
                                             Layout: FillLayout {type=SWT.HORIZONTAL}
                                             LayoutData: null
                                            Composite {} [layout=GridLayout {makeColumnsEqualWidth=true horizontalSpacing=5 verticalSpacing=10}]@1776752
                                                 Style: LEFT_TO_RIGHT 
                                                 Bounds: Rectangle {0, 0, 1120, 238}
                                                 Layout: GridLayout {makeColumnsEqualWidth=true horizontalSpacing=5 verticalSpacing=10}
                                                 LayoutData: null
```

Here is an example which demonstrates the problem:

```
@Override
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    Composite panel = new Composite(parent, 0);
    panel.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    viewer = new TreeViewer(panel);
    viewer.setContentProvider(new ITreeContentProvider() {
        @Override
        public Object[] getChildren(Object parentElement) {
            return new Object[0];
        }
        @Override
        public Object getParent(Object element) {
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean hasChildren(Object element) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public Object[] getElements(Object inputElement) {
            if(inputElement instanceof Integer[]) {
                return (Object[]) inputElement;
            }
            return new Object[0];
        }
    });
        
    final TreeViewerColumn viewerColumn = new TreeViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.NONE);
    viewerColumn.setLabelProvider(new CellLabelProvider() {
        @Override
        public void update(ViewerCell cell) {
            cell.setText(cell.getElement().toString());
        }
    });
    final TreeColumn column = viewerColumn.getColumn();
    column.setText("HEADER");
    column.setWidth(150);
        
    Integer[] content = new Integer[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
    viewer.setInput(content);
    viewer.getTree().setHeaderVisible(true);
}
```

(When creating this example, I noticed that the problem appeared after I added a column. With no specific columns only one scrollbar is shown)

What might be causing this?

Comment: Is the tree inside something with its own scroll bar - so one bar from the tree and one from the container? `ScrolledForm` used by the Form toolkit is one such container.

Comment: No. They are simply placed in a `Composite`. AFAIK there are no `ScrolledForms`.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with that code, but I am using macOS where scroll bars are rather different. I am also using 2023-09.

Comment: @greg-449 I switched to 2023-09 and still have the same issue (Windows 11) I will try to repeat it in a new RCP app...

Comment: @greg-449 it works correctly in a separate app. Perhaps a CSS setting :-/ ? Must be something central which affects Viewers in different Views...

Comment: The TreeViewer in your example code isn't instantiated with style bits, so it "is created using the SWT style bits MULTI, H_SCROLL, V_SCROLL, and BORDER" (from the JavaDoc), meaning it'll have scroll bars if it has more content than its size can fit. It's unclear from the JavaDoc if those are ignored when you *do* pass in style bits. Check the source.

Answer (score 0):

I am using 2 monitors: the notebook and a 32" screen. The first scales to 100%, the second to 150%.

If I move the app from the second to the first, the app renders correctly.

I altered the windows configuration to scale screen 2 at 100% and the app renders correctly on both screens.

This explains the dodgy rendering but not sure how to handle this for all the different workstations where the app will be deployed...